# Push another view controller into a UITabBarController view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller

For the navigation in my app I'm using a UITabBarController. This works fine, but in one of my viewcontrollers I want to push another view controller into the tabbar view.
In other words I want to replace the selected viewcontroller with another one.
I'm doing this with the following code:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = self.otherViewController;
```

The list of viewControllers in my TabBarController does not contain the otherViewController.
This trick works fine in IOS 4.3, but IOS 5 does not like it.

Does anyone know a solution which is accepted by IOS 5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to REPLACE that view controller in the tabbar with another view Controller?
If so, you have to edit the viewControllers property in the tabbar by setting a new one. It would be something like:

```
UIViewController *thisIsTheViewControllerIWantToSetNow;
int indexForViewControllerYouWantToReplace;

NSMutableArray *tabbarViewControllers = [self.tabbar.viewControllers mutableCopy];

[tabbarViewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:indexForViewControllerYouWantToReplace withObject:thisIsTheViewControllerIWantToSetNow];

self.tabbar.viewControllers = tabbarViewControllers;

[tabbarViewControllers release];
```

Comment: This works, but you have to take a NSMutableArray (a mutableCopy of your viewController array)

Comment: Oh yes, you're right, I typed that without Xcode to make me realize replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject doesn't exist unless it's an NSMUTABLEArray

Comment: That's wỏk, but the icon of tabbar are missing and when i touch another tab and touch back, when changing view it's "lag", i think

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use a navigation controller or similar on this tab?

Anyway this should work:

```
NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:rootTabBarController.viewControllers];
[controllers replaceObjectAtIndex:rootTabBarController.selectedIndex withObject: newController];
rootTabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```